# serach substring on arm 32 bits

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I have register r0 that point on address (for ex. I call it `X`).

On this address there is :  `0x112233445566778899001122334455667788AABBCC11223344.....`

I want search if in address x+0x12 there is string `AABBCC11223344`.

```
ldr r3,[r0,#0x12]
cmp r3, #0xAA
BNE Error

ldr r3,[r0,#0x13]
cmp r3, #0xBB
BNE Error

ldr r3,[r0,#0x14]
cmp r3, #0xCC
BNE Error

ldr r3,[r0,#0x15]
cmp r3, #0x11
BNE Error

......
```

The problem is that even the first check(if ro+0x12==AA) got wrong.

What is wrong?

And how can I do this check more beautiful(without loop)

Comment: `ldr r3,[r0,#0x12]` is a 32-bit load.  You want `ldb`.  Or better, since your hardware didn't fault on unaligned loads, use `ldr` and then compare against a 32-bit constant.  e.g. `ldr r2, =0xAABBCC11` / `ldr r3,[r0,#0x12]` / `cmp r3, r2` / `BNE Error`.

Comment: Yes, use a debugger and see.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, please answer me on the follow 1) why I can translate only `ldr r3,[r0,#0x10]` or `ldr r3,[r0,#0x14]` to bytes with http://armconverter.com/ and I can't translate  `ldr r3,[r0,#0x12]` or  `ldr r3,[r0,#0x11]`?    I want load o register `ldr r3,[r0,#0x12]`         ..........2)how can I compare the last 24 bites? (`223344`)  ..........3)can you recommend me on simple debugger that I can debug some like this?(push values to address and run command and see what's happened , thank you!!!

Comment: GDB works well.  It's not also a simulator, though.  It's usually easiest to change the source and re-assemble to try with different instructions or data.  But you can use the `set` command on memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes , can you please answer me on 1 and 2 please ?(last reply)

Comment: Calm down, it took me 2 minutes to find the answer.  Sounds like you're assembling for Thumb2, [which requires the displacement to be a multiple of 4 for `ldr`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489h/CIHGJHED.html).  `ldrb` doesn't have this limitation (but can only access a smaller range because the value isn't scaled by 4), while ARM mode allows any byte displacement from -4096 to +4095.

Comment: @PeterCordes I on Thumb-2 . `ldr r2, =0xAABBCC11` translate to 4 instruction in hex http://armconverter.com/  `004A
FFFF00BF
FF    BBFFFF`

Comment: http://armconverter.com/ probably uses an assembler option to avoid literal pools.  It would normally assemble to a constant in memory and a PC-relative load.  I'm only seeing three instructions for it on that site; and I didn't disassemble the machine code; maybe it's a jmp over the constant as well.

Comment: what is the maximum byte that I can compare with only 1 hex instruction ? ldrb give me 1 byte, how can I get with ldb more than 1 byte please?

Comment: Load the first 4 or 8 bytes of the search pattern into one or two registers *outside your loops*; it doesn't matter as much how many instructions it takes then.

Comment: @PeterCordes I so thank you about al but I not get you.  I want to check all of this 7 or 8 bytes with the least machine code. can you please explain me how to do it? (or maybe if you can write I will thank you!)

Comment: I had a half-finished answer but my browser lost it :/  If you don't want to loop over every byte, you need a fancy algorithm like Boyer-Moore.  You can also get speedups from SIMD, potentially, but ARM NEON is much worse for this than x86 SSE2, I think.  e.g. see https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse4-strstr/blob/master/neon-strstr-v2.cpp (NEON `strst`) https://community.arm.com/tools/f/discussions/424/neon-fast-128-bit-comparison https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/216bff9ff33d74fb7f232045799a93b102a4d2a2/libc/arch-arm64/generic/bionic/strchr.S (NEON strchr implementations)